# If two Brownian motion starts and end at the same points, can we say something about there difference?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, random-walk, levy-processes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two standard Brownian motions with mean $0$ and variance $1$, both started at zero. If we know that
\begin{align}
   X_n &= Y_n,
\end{align}
for some $n>0$, can we say something about
\begin{align}
   &X_t - Y_t, \text{ or } \tag{1}\\
   &|X_t - Y_t|, \text{ or } \tag{2}\\
   &\max |X_t - Y_t | . \tag{3}
\end{align}
when $0 \le t \le n$.

I tried to find the expected square difference
$$
E\left( |X_t - Y_t|^2 \Big| X_n = Y_n \right),
$$
without success. I tried to view the problem as a random walk, thought about excursion theory, still without success.

I need information on either (1), (2) or (3) in other to bound some quantity in another problem.

Comment: @ Nicolas Essis-Breton : Hi this question looks closely related to Brownian Bridges. I suggest you take a look at the problem for Bronwnian bridges, specifying with care the way you link the two bridges, this should allow to get the result in the conditioned case (those are marginnaly gaussian processes so calculation should be tractable once the joint law is specfied) . Then taking the expectation with respect the law of the terminal value should lead you to something. Best regards